# How to reorder bottom navigation bar buttons?

Tags: buttons, navigation-bar

Is there any way to reorder the soft buttons at the bottom navigation bar on Android?
I have a tablet (Teclast X98, KitKat), which has the following layout:

[image: Original Layout]

This layout is really bad, because the tablet is big and you can't reach the back button with either thumb when holding the tablet with two hands. So it means constantly letting go of the tablet with the other hand to push the back button. Extremely annoying :(

I would like to reoder them to something like this:

[image: Preferred Layout]

Which would make it much better for two-handed navigation. Now the back button would be within easy reach for the left hand thumb.

Is there any system file where the button layout is defined, or any app or Xposed module that could help?

Comment: GravityBox, or SoftkeyZ. Might help.

Comment: I'm not sure which of those can work on these "soft-keys" – but be welcome to check my app list on [Edit Key Settings](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546).